# getting numbers for theorems, propositions,

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want to number theorems (or propositions,...) as Theorem 1.1 and Theorem 1.A simultaneously in a text? In fact, I don't know how to mark some theorems (or propositions,...) as Theorem 1.A, Theorem 1.B,...? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a little mock-up document showing the settings used to define your theorem structures?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You might want to take a look at the following packages [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem), [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools).

Comment: You might be able to answer your own question with information here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to have two theorem-like structures with the same name, but one with arabic numbering and the other one with alphabetic numbering; here's an illustration using the `amsthm` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{atheo}{Theorem}[chapter]

\renewcommand\theatheo{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{atheo}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{theo}
Test theorem with arabic numbering.
\end{theo}
\begin{atheo}
Test theorem with alphabetic numbering.
\end{atheo}
\begin{atheo}
Another test theorem with alphabetic numbering.
\end{atheo}
\begin{theo}
Another test theorem with arabic numbering.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Gonzalo Medina

Comment: Dear Gonzalo Medina   It was so helpful..thank you very much..thank you

Comment: @AzadehNikseresht you're welcome! If you consider my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Yes, your answer solved my problem. I will certainly do it.